# Trying to initialise a new struct for every connection in server-client program without writing over the previous

Tags: c, struct

So basically i've got a client-server chat program using sockets and threads that can hold multiple clients. What i'm trying to do is on client connection the server acts this newly created client struct to a linked list so that there is a record of each connected user. 
But it seems after the first user is connected and struct is added, the second one connects and overwrites it.

```
typedef struct client client_t;
typedef struct node node_t;

node_t *client_list = NULL;

struct client {
    int ID;
    int sockID;
};

struct node {
    client_t *client;
    node_t *next;
};

node_t * node_add(node_t *head, client_t *c) {
    node_t *new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    new->client = c;
    new->next = head;
    return new;
}

int main() {

    while(1) {
        client_t client;
        client.sockID = accept(server_socket, (struct sockaddr *) &client.clientaddress, &client.len);
        client.ID = client_count + 1;

        if (pthread_create(&thread[client_count], NULL, network, (void *) &client) == 0) {
            node_t *new = node_add(client_list, &client);
            client_list = new;
       }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I imagine its the fact that i'm declaring 'client_t client' and its just overwriting the previous with a new connection. Is there a way around this if I dont want to hard code every clients name..

Comment: Where's the code for `node_add()`?  Does it make a copy of the client structure it is passed, or does it simply put the pointer into the list?  If it merely puts the pointer, you get the overwriting effect.  You need to make a copy of the structure, somehow.

Comment: Er... Give each thread it's own newly malloced structure instead of using a temporary one that you really shouldn't be dereferencing after that particular iteration of the while loop ends

Comment: I've added in node_add() if that helps now

Comment: If I connect 2 clients and print the linked list, it will print 2 nodes, but instead of being say client - id: 1, client - id: 2. I will overwrite and have both showing as the latest id. In this case, client- id: 2, client - id: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to study the C memory model more closely. Your code contains an error common for new C programmers. The data structure you want is something like this:

```
struct node {
    client_t client;  // Not a pointer!
    node_t *next;
};
```

As you've defined it, the node only stores a pointer to a `client_t`. You allocate a `client_t` as a local (C auto) variable and pass a pointer to it into the node allocator, but that local variable has a scope that ends after every loop iteration.

With the new definition, the client record in the node lasts until you explicitly `free()` it.

The matching update to the node allocator is

```
node_t * node_add(node_t *head, client_t *c) {
    node_t *new = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new == NULL) {
        return NULL;
    }
    new->client = *c; // Copy the entire client into the node.
    new->next = head;
    return new;
}
```

The commented line is a `struct` assignment. It copies both fields of the `client_t` into the node.

To use the client info that's now stored in the node, you'll use `.` rather than `->`:  for example `node->client.ID`.